# Are call back functions same as nested functions?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, callback, jquery-callback, nested-function

I have been programming in different languages. Recently, I got an opportunity to start to know `jQuery`. I was reading about call back functions and I understood what it meant(for doing things in a particular manner, one after the other.) I am a bit confused either to relate them with nested functions or not? Isn't it the same thing? Please help out to clear the concept. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A callback function is any function which is invoked when an operation is complete. It doesn't really matter where it was defined: you can create a locally scoped function, a globally scoped, etc.

Using `$.ajax` as an example, where `success` is the callback:

```
function handleSuccess(data) {
   $(document.body).append(data);
}

function doAjaxCall() {
   $.ajax({url: 'some/path', success: handleSuccess });
}
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
function doAjaxCall() {
   var handleSuccess = function(data) {
       $(document.body).append(data);
   }

   $.ajax({ url: 'some/path', success: handleSuccess });
}
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
function doAjaxCall() { 
   $.ajax({ url: 'some/path', success: function(data) {
       $(document.body).append(data);
    }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Callback function is just a function which performs a callback. :) So first you need to call, which is actually any operation. Consider this example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/test/'
});
```

This method calls our server. Now the operation is asynchronous - we do not know when the server is going to respond. But we do know what kind of data it will give us. So you define callback - the operation you are going to perform after server responds. In this case you may define `success` callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/test/',
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

Callbacks need not be asynchronous. Consider this example

```
function test(data, callback) {
    if (callback && $.isFunction(callback))
        callback(data);
}
```

The jQuery method `isFunction` only checks if `callback` is a function. Now you can call `test` like this

```
test('test_string', function(str) {
   console.log(str);
});
```

The function passed as a second argument is a callback.

So basically callback is nothing else then a function passed as an argument to another function. Mostly used for asynchronous operations but not only (life example: method `forEach` of Array object).

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong but I think the question is:

```
$("#someDiv").fadeIn(200, function(){
        //do some stuff 
    });

vs

$("#someDiv").fadeIn(200, callbackFunction);
function callbackFunction()
{
    //do some stuff
}
```

(Sorry for posting this as an answer not a comment, but comments do not have code formatting)

Comment: Actually, comments do have `code formatting` (between backticks) :)

Comment: Hmmm... not really: `$("#someDiv").fadeIn(200, function(){
        //do some stuff 
    });

vs

$("#someDiv").fadeIn(200, callbackFunction);
function callbackFunction()
{
    //do some stuff
}
`